# Surface at +(...)% colors in jetpack compose

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, material-you

In official Material Design 3 resources (e.g. the Figma design kit), there have been many references to colors called "Surface at +x". These colors are the surface color mixed with x% of the primary color.

Now my question:

**How can you implement the "Surface at +x" colors in Jetpack Compose?** There is no documentation and no property on the `MaterialTheme.colorScheme` object.

Figma Design Kit reference: [image: Colors in the Figma Material Design 3 UI Kit]

Comment: Have you tried `ColorUtils.blendARGB(color1, color2, 0.12f)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface uses `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface` by default, they also have a new `tonalElevation` property which you can read about [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/material#m3-elevation).

The gist of it is that increasing the tonal elevation changes the color automatically, try it yourself:

```
Surface(tonalElevation = 5.dp) {
    // content
}
```

Answer (score 7):

### Update September 2022

With Material 3, if for some reason you need the **elevate color surface** but you can't use the `Surface`, now you can use directly:

```
MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceColorAtElevation(4.dp)
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone need to get it in a non-compose code, use *SurfaceColors enums*:

```
int colorSurface1 = SurfaceColors.SURFACE_2.getColor(context);
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/color-theming)